# Confusion about bookdown structure

Tags: bookdown

I have spent a very frustrating day trying to figure out how to use Bookdown to put together a simple course syllabus, using the chapter structure for weekly course units.

The first confusion was to do with the mismatched chapter numbering in the package: it turns out that index.Rmd also includes Chapter 1, so as a result 01-intro.Rmd turns out to be Chapter 2, 02 is Chapter 3 etc. I figured this out. The main problem is how to insert a non-numbered page at the beginning, before the numbered chapters themselves begin. This is necessary for a syllabus to provide basic course information, description, etc. One of the three sample syllabi on the RStudio website includes such a page, but I can find no information on how to add it before the numbered chapters.

A course syllabus would appear to be a standard use case, yet I have found little documentation on how to actually do it, only examples of pre-built syllabi.

The documentation on bookdown, blogdown, etc. is extensive but often repetitive, while Googling, for example, " <chapter structure" just leads to more similar-looking online books about authoring online books. Altogether, for something so supposedly simple, I feel like I am going round in circles.

Answer (score 1):

You can exclude numbers from chapters (or sections), by appending {-} at the end of the line.

For example,

```
# This is my unnumbered chapter title {-}
```

[This is the section](https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/markdown-syntax.html#block-level-elements) of the documentation that mentions it.